# PocketSphinx: Getting the probabilities of the words

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

I use PocketSphinx to do voice recognition. For example I use a language model like this:

- Hello
- Hi
- World
- Earth

I say "Hello world", now I want the list of the probabilities/scores of the recognition. Like for the first word "Hello" a possible match could be:

- "Hello" 90%
- "Hi" 10%
- "World" 30%
- "Earth" 30%

I don't know how PocketSphinx represents the probabilities. It is only an example. Has someone a clue?

Thanks

Mosa

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve individual segments of hypothesis with iterator:

```
 print 'Best hypothesis segments: ', [(seg.word, seg.prob) for seg in decoder.seg()]
```

seg.prob contains the confidence score. To have a meaningful confidence score you need to make sure your language model is large enough.

For small single phrase spotting it's better to use keyword spotting mode.

Comment: Thx, for your help, but I can't find any documention about this. I use ROS and this code https://github.com/mikeferguson/pocketsphinx/blob/indigo-devel/nodes/recognizer.py
Where I  get the segment?